# Clear all entries from bcdedit

Tags: batch, bcdedit, bcdboot

I was wondering if anyone had a batch file that cleared ALL entries from BCDEdit.

I plan on using bcdboot to insert the correct boot entry after it is cleared.

**Note:** I am not authorized to use third party software.

Answer (score 3):

[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) has a feature to "reset BCD" to a clean condition, with no entries. It's free.

Disclosure: I'm the author.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not authorized to use third party software.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.

**Warning - make sure you realize the repercussions.** After clearing, your system will not boot back into windows. You'll almost certainly want to run another command before restarting - I give an example at then end. **I've only tested this on UEFI systems**

From an elevated command prompt, do the following:

```
bcdedit /createstore c:\emptystore
bcdedit /import c:\emptystore /clean
```

If you want your system to reboot back into the windows installed at c:\windows, you will want to run this from the same prompt before restarting:

```
bcdboot c:\windows
```