# How to diagnose and fix Starting Bitlocker "Access Denied" message?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I've been trying to get my C: drive to use BitLocker, but it fails at some initializing step.

Is there a log or some other method that will explain the issue?

I've searched event logs etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It was due to incorrect BCD settings, Recovery was incorrectly specified. So clearing BCD with BCDEdit and resetting the recovery agent fixed the issue. (Make sure you know what your are doing when you reset BCD! )

Reset BCD
https://superuser.com/a/1246611/5561

Reset Recovery:
http://woshub.com/restoring-windows-recovery-environment-winre-in-windows-10/#h2_4

Answer (score 13):

Are you enabled BitLocker via RDP? If yes, please enable the following group policy:
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Removable Storage Access > All Removable Storage > Allow direct access in remote sessions

If no, try to enable it as an Administrator.

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you random Internet hero, this fixed my personal issue!